# Problem connecting Visual Studio HDInsight Emulator to Hive on a YARN cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, visual-studio-2017, azure-hdinsight

I want to use Visual Studio to query from hive which is installed on a YARN cluster under Centos7 X64. The Cluster has a master node and 4 worker nodes. I already succeeded the connection to WebHDFS and SSH but can not connect to HiveServer2. All services are up and running including HDFS, YARN and HiveServer2.

I've set port 10000 for HiveServer2 in hive-site.xml and the Web UI is being shown on port 10002. I installed hive ODBC driver and configured it. It successfully connects to my HiveServer2 on port 10000.

The HDInsight Emulator just shows 'Failed to open connection. Please check your connection string. See inner exception for failure details' I tried 10000, 10001 and 10002 port numbers but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

**Steps to connect HDInsight emulator using Visual Studio:**

1. Open Visual Studio, select View, and then select Server Explorer.
2. From Server Explorer, right-click the HDInsight entry, and then select Connect to HDInsight Emulator.

[image: Screenshot of Server Explorer, with Connect to HDInsight Emulator highlighted]

3. From the Connect to HDInsight Emulator dialog box, enter the password that you configured for Ambari. Select Next to continue.

[image: Screenshot of dialog box, with password text box highlighted]

4. Use the Password field to enter the password you configured for the root account. Leave the other fields at the default value. Select Next to continue.

[image: Screenshot of dialog box, with password text box highlighted]

5. Wait for validation of the services to finish. In some cases, validation may fail and prompt you to update the configuration. If validation fails, select Update, and wait for the configuration and verification for the service to finish.

[image]

6. After validation has finished, select Finish to complete configuration.

[image]

For more details, refer "[How to use HDInsight emulator using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-emulator-visual-studio)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't use HortonWorks Sandbox. My cluster has been deployed on real servers. I've done the above steps (and also what the link mentioned) but I still can't connect to Hive.

Comment: What do you mean by "The HDInsight Emulator just shows 'Failed to open connection."? How exactly are you connecting real servers via HDInsight Emulator?

Comment: To be clear, I have 5 servers running Centos with YARN cluster, HDFS and hive running on them. The cluster is already operational and I can commit hive queries in Linux terminal. What I need is to connect VS2017 to my master node to commit hive queries remotely.